# How can I control spacing between lines within a PdfPCell?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I'm attempting to generate PDFs for college transcripts using itext 5.5.9. I've decided on using PdfPTable for controlling the layout. The beginning of the document includes an overview section with the following lines:

Name:
Date of Birth:

Major:
Minor:

Right now the output adds more space between these lines than desired. (It looks as if the lines are double-spaced.) Here are code snippets that seem relevant:

```
PdfPCell overviewCell = new PdfPCell();
//other codes here...

overviewCell.setPadding(0f);;       
overviewCell.setLeading(0f, 0f);

overviewCell.addElement(new Phrase("Name:", normalFont));
overviewCell.addElement(Chunk.NEWLINE);
overviewCell.addElement(new Phrase("Date of Birth:", normalFont));
overviewCell.addElement(Chunk.NEWLINE);
overviewCell.addElement(Chunk.NEWLINE);
overviewCell.addElement(new Phrase("Major:", normalFont));
```

I also tried obtaining the PdfWriter's `ColumnText (ct)`, and working with that object directly before calling `overviewCell.setColumn(ct)` but that didn't fix the spacing either.

Please let me know how do control the text's line spacing within the cell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add create a sub table and add it to the overview cell with your desired amount. This will handle a lot of the formatting for you.

```
private static final String _name = "Name:";
private static final String _dateOfBirth = "Date Of Birth:";
private static final String _major = "Major:";

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

PdfPCell spaceCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", normalFont));
PdfPCell nameCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_name, normalFont));
PdfPCell dateOfBirthCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_dateOfBirth, normalFont));
PdfPcell majorCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_major, normalFont));

table.addCell(nameCell);
table.addCell(spaceCell);
table.addCell(dateOfBirthCell);
table.addCell(spaceCell);
table.addCell(spaceCell); // if you want an extra line break here a fill a line
table.addCell(spaceCell); // with space cells
table.addCell(majorCell);

overviewCell.addElement(table);
```

Comment: Great suggestion! I was just thinking of making each phrase a cell (row) in the main table, but I like your idea of a sub-table. Thanks, Sam! (Because I'm new here, my upvote for your reply doesn't count.)

Comment: No problem man.  Glad I could help.  You can accept the answer